# create new image style using javascript

Tags: javascript, media

I am using fancybox JS library for creating a slideshow from a custom bloc with a multivalue image field.

it works but the images on the slideshow are small because a style have been applied to the images.

I then get the original size image using a substring JS function but it is not entirely satisfying

```
(function ($, Drupal) {

  $('.bloc-image-gallery img').each(function (){
    var currentImage = $(this);
    var path=currentImage.attr("src");
    var StyleCutPath = path.substring(
      path.lastIndexOf("/") -7,
      path.lastIndexOf("?")
    );
    currentImage.wrap('<a class="fancybox" data-fancybox="gallery" href="/sites/my_site/files/' + StyleCutPath + '"></a>'); });

  Drupal.behaviors.fancyBoxInit = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $('[data-fancybox="gallery"]', context).once('fancyBoxInit').fancybox({
        buttons: [
          'close'
        ]
      });
    }
  }
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

I wonder how i could get the href with an new style applied to it ( bigger image but not original size )

The src takes this form

> /sites/my_site/files/styles/directory_user_photo/public/2018-09/seminary.png?itok=5597asHF

i made it to

> /sites/my_site/files/2018-09/seminary.png

but i would rather have smthg as

> /sites/my_site/files/styles/my_new_style_adapted_to_full_screen_visio/public/2018-09/seminary.png?itok=5597asHF

Comment: In the field formatter settings you can tell the image to render in one style, but link through to the full image. If that doesn't suit, I'd consider creating a new field formatter which gives you the option to link through to another image style. Doing it in JS is always going to be a hack because the URL generation functions live in PHP

Comment: I would advise a completely different solution: Create a responsive image style with all meaningful image styles included and let the browser do the job of selecting the proper image source.

Comment: @clive ok, i see it in the image media display render. But this does not allow to link to a new style

Comment: @Hudri mm taht is a module is it? , not sure that would work for my purpose. i am happy about the size but i like to change it on click when the slideshow opens

Comment: thanks clive, interesting that new formatter. this has never been done by the community before ?

Comment: @Matoeil My idea is to use the same `img srcset` of the small preview image also as `data-srcset` for Fancybox' JS large image. By theory the browser should select the small src for the block and Fancybox should load the large src for the lightbox

Comment: Sorry, after rethinking it, I think my idea will most likely not work. You would need a size/src based on a container query, but responsive images in browsers only work with media queries = screen width/height.

Comment: at least u made me discover that not activated by default core module

Answer (score 0):

clive would suggest to create a new Formatter for image type fields that would allow in the render display to select a image style for the image link.

At least i could do "In the field formatter settings you can tell the image to render in one style, but link through to the full image" and clean the code to:

```
(function ($, Drupal) {

  Drupal.behaviors.fancyBoxInit = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $('[data-fancybox="gallery"]', context).once('fancyBoxInit').fancybox({
        buttons: [
          'close'
        ]
      });
    }
  }
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

with in image-formatter--media--image--field-media-image.html.twig

```
   {% if url %}
      <a data-fancybox="group" href="{{ url }}">{{ image }}</a>
    {% else %}
      {{ image }}
    {% endif %}
```